# How can I apply padding to both the TextField input and label in Material UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, material-ui, material-design

I have started using Material UI for a project. I created a TextField for a form field as shown below. I am trying to apply padding to this input field as demonstrated below, but the label is not being affected by this padding.

```
<TextField
          sx={{ display: "flex", padding: "20px 0px" }}
          name="mail"
          label="Email"
          type="mail"
          id="mail"
          placeholder="Enter email"
          variant="standard"
          inputProps={{
            sx: {  fontSize: "13px", marginTop: "4px" }
          }}
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true,
            sx: {
             fontSize: "12px"
            }
          }}
        />
```

What should I do in order to provide padding to the input along with the label?

Answer (score 1):

The label is not affected by your padding changes because it is `position: absolute` making it a `positioned element`. You can move the label around by adding `top, left, bottom, right` props to the `InputLabelProps` `sx` value.

```
InputLabelProps={{
  shrink: true,
  sx: {
   fontSize: "12px",
   left: "1rem",
   right: "1rem",
  }
}}
```

Here is a [Code Sandbox repro](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-text-field-input-label-padding-h33v2w?file=/src/App.tsx) with the label moved to align with the inputs padding.

And here's a screenshot showing the result of adding `top` and `left` values to the `InputLabelProps` styling

[image: text field UI screenshot]

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 1):

The input label has the absolute position. So padding and margin will not work here. top, bottom, right, and left positions will work. You can try the below code.

```
<TextField        
    name="mail"
    label="Email"
    type="mail"
    id="mail"
    variant="standard"
    placeholder="Enter email"
    inputProps={{
      sx: { fontSize: "13px", marginTop: "4px" },
    }}
    InputLabelProps={{
      shrink: true,
      sx: {
        fontSize: "12px",
        bottom: "20px"
      },
    }}
  />
```